# Online quests Wii U and 3DS Monster Hunter 3 Ultimate

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, wii-u, monster-hunter-3-ultimate

I have been playing a lot MH3U on Wii U, and also my son... He has a 3DS, and I'd like to play online quest with him, and another players around.
If i buy a 3DS cartdrige of this game, we can join online quests simultaneosly? For example, I play on Wii U, and he plays on 3DS, at the same time, in the same online quest, with other two any players?

Comment: I vaguely recall that this is not really possible. The 3ds cartridge has no native online ability, and when connected to the wii-u it occupies the wii-u's wifi capabilities, meaning you need a wired internet connection, which requires a usb converter and a specific app from the e-store. And I'm not sure the Wii-u game can go online with the 3ds game connected.

Comment: I remember researching this as my roommate had the wii-u version and I the 3ds. But I can't remember if we abandoned trying to go online together because it was not possible, or because the extra cost and effort was not worth it.

Comment: My Wii U uses wired connection... maybe the 3DS could use the wi-fi...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You can't.](https://www.nintendo.co.uk/Support/Wii-U/Game-Tips/Monster-Hunter-3-Ultimate/Monster-Hunter-3-Ultimate-Packet-Relay-Tools/Monster-Hunter-3-Ultimate-Packet-Relay-Tools-736395.html) The 3DS version of Monster Hunter 3 Ultimate can only access online capabilities when a certain app is run from the Wii U. The only way to play multiplayer locally would be through the use of Monster Hunter 4 Ultimate with multiple 3DS systems.